# Use fasttext for the character embeddings?

Tags: embedding, fasttext

We have pre-trained fast text word embeddings. Can we use it find the character embeddings. Although I found a blog [This link](http://minimaxir.com/2017/04/char-embeddings/). But in this blog author has just averaged the character over all the words. Is there any other way to have character embeddings without training the RNN or CNN.

Comment: AFAIK, `fasttext` doesn't provide any way to train char level embeddings. skipgram, cbow and the subword-aware solution of Mikolov et al isn't reasonable for characters.